# Getting guild members via fetch takes really long and an exception gets thrown

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, discord.js

```
guild = client.guilds.cache.get("guildid");
guild.members.fetch().then(fetchedMembers=>{console.log(fetchedMembers.length)})
```

Using discord.js v12, I'm trying to get all the members of a guild using the fetch function, and then get a random username from the members list. The first line, getting the guild from the specific id works just fine, and executes pretty much instantaneously. However, even after waiting for minutes, I can't seem to fetch the members from the guild. Instead this error gets thrown after some time-:

```
(node:40774) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT]: Members didn't arrive in time.
at timeout.client.setTimeout (/home/k/n/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildMemberManager.js:317:16)
at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/home/k/n/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:83:7)
at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

What's the problem and how do I fix it???

Answer (score 0):

I have done a little bit of research and it seems there is a way to fix this by using intents properly.

You should create your client like this:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ ws: { intents: ['GUILD_MEMBERS', Intents.NON_PRIVILEGED] } });
```

It will fix the issue of GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT.

Make sure you have enabled the "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT" on your Developer Portal.